# LLM ignoring system prompt in llamaindex

Tags: large-language-model, llama-index, vector-database

```
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

from llama_index.llms.mistralai import MistralAI
from llama_index.embeddings.mistralai import MistralAIEmbedding
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.core.tools import QueryEngineTool, ToolMetadata
from llama_index.core.query_engine import SubQuestionQueryEngine
from prompts import new_prompt, instruction_str

llm = MistralAI(model="mistral-large-latest", temperature=0.1, system_prompt="Act like your mad, and use the word banana in every word")

embed_model = MistralAIEmbedding(model_name="mistral-embed")

Settings.llm = llm
Settings.embed_model = embed_model

gameRules = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./data/game_rules.txt"]).load_data()
gameMemories = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./data/game-memory.txt"]).load_data()

gameRules_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(gameRules)
gameRules_query_engine = gameRules_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=5, instruction_str=instruction_str)

gameMemories_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(gameMemories)
gameMemories_query_engine = gameMemories_index.as_query_engine(sisimilarity_top_k=5)

query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=gameRules_query_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="gameRules",
            description="Provides information about the game rules"
        ),
    ),
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=gameMemories_query_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="gameMemories",
            description="Provides information about the game Memories of the agent"
        ),
    ),
]

sub_question_query_engine = SubQuestionQueryEngine.from_defaults(
    query_engine_tools=query_engine_tools, llm=llm)

from llama_index.core.agent import ReActAgent

agent = ReActAgent.from_tools(llm=llm, verbose=True)  

response = agent.chat("tell me about the moon landing")
print(response)
```

I'm trying to make the LLM respond in a certain way. Here, for the example, I tried to make him sound mad and use the word banana in his response.

I ask him to talk about the moon landing in the agent prompt. It completely ignores the system prompt in the answer.

**His answer**:

> The moon landing refers to the event that occurred on July 20, 1969,
> when astronauts Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin became the first humans
> to land on the moon as part of the Apollo 11 mission. Armstrong was
> the first to step onto the lunar surface, followed by Aldrin. They
> spent about two and a half hours outside the spacecraft, collecting
> lunar material to bring back to Earth. The event was a significant
> achievement in human space exploration and was watched by millions of
> people around the world